Is this a gas line or water line in my kitchen?
I just purchased and older home and I’m looking to install the refrigerator. I’m the space where the fridge is designated to go there is the piping coming out of the wall. The oven is on the opposite side of the space. It is was wall oven connected to a gas line. I would like to install a refrigerator with an ice maker but not sure if this a gas pipe or water.

Look under the sinks (kitchen & bath), down in the basement, etc. See if there is any matching piping and if so, where it goes. That'd probably be your best bet.

If the house has iron water pipes elsewhere, this might be a water pipe. If the only other iron pipes are for gas, this probably is, too. Though usually gas would have a shutoff valve - then again so would water. Is the thing on top a plug or an open fitting? Shutoff might be in basement?

Caution: Natural gas refrigerators used to be commonplace. This might be a gas line. https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/0jMAAOSwx7Riu7ab/s-l960.jpg

I do not know, but I am leaning more to gas pipe.  Older homes usually did not have fridges with water, not as common.  It does depend on what older means.  90s or 2000 might be older, or 30s to 40s

My grandparents had a gas (ammonia/water cycle) fridge, as @MTA described.
